# Inserting a tuple field in Cassandra with python driver

Tags: python, cassandra, tuples

everybody,

I have a problem inserting data into a tuple-valued field on a Cassandra table through the `python-driver` provided by DataStax.

Either I don't get how to properly pass the tuple argument to the `Session.execute` command or the driver is transforming the tuple, internally, in the wrong way when dispatching it to Cassandra - because the same insertion works fine when performed in a `cqlsh` session.

An equivalent insertion involving not a tuple, rather a list, works fine both in-code and in `cqlsh`.

I am using Python 2.7.10 and cassandra-driver 3.7.1. The error which gets raised in the Python execution is `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid list literal for tuplefield of type frozen<tuple<int, int, int>>"`.

I paste below a minimal working code that reproduces the issue I am seeing. Could someone help me figure out whether am I doing something wrong?

(Note: I have tried already to pass an ordinary List to `Session.execute` in place of the tuple argument, with no luck either.)

Thank you very much.

```
'''
    Run with:
        python 2.7.10
        cassandra-driver==3.7.1 installed
'''

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

if __name__=='__main__':

    serverAddress='SERVER_ADDRESS'
    keyspacename='tupletests'
    tablecreation='''create table tabletest (
                            rowid int,
                            tuplefield tuple < int, int, int >,
                            listfield list < int >,
                        primary key (rowid)
                    );'''

    # connect and create keyspace
    clu=Cluster([serverAddress])
    session=clu.connect()
    session.execute("create keyspace %s with replication = \
        {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};" % keyspacename)

    # use keyspace; create a sample table
    session.set_keyspace(keyspacename)
    session.execute(tablecreation)

    # insert a row with rowid,listfield
    session.execute('insert into tabletest (rowid, listfield) values (%s,%s)', \
        [999, [10,11,12]])
    # succeeds

    # insert a row with rowid,tuplefield
    session.execute('insert into tabletest (rowid, tuplefield) values (%s,%s)', \
        [111, tuple([6,5,4])])
    # raises: *** InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
    # message="Invalid list literal for tuplefield of type frozen<tuple<int, int, int>>"

    # Compare with analogous statements in cqlsh, which *both* succeed:
    # List:    insert into tabletest (rowid, listfield) values (999, [21,22,23]);
    # Tuple:   insert into tabletest (rowid, tuplefield) values (765, (121,122,123));

    # delete test keyspace
    session.execute("drop keyspace %s;" % keyspacename)    
    print "Test Finished."
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just solved the issue. Posting solution here for everybody.
In order to let the driver know how the tuple should be formatted when passing it to Cassandra, if insisting on using a non-prepared statement for the insert, one must specify the encoder to use when parsing tuples before invoking the insert:

```
session.encoder.mapping[tuple] = session.encoder.cql_encode_tuple
```

After this statement, tuples appearing in `Session.execute` insert statements are automatically cast in the right way for Cassandra, which does not complain anymore.

(as far as I understand, it is even better to resort to a Prepared statement, which contains enough information to make it superfluous to specify the encoder separately).